# recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function which take an integer  ,n, and give all the even number to zero and then every number to n...

*this is what I have so far*

```
def kaboom(n):
   if n>=0:
     if n%2==0:
           print n,
           print kaboom(n-2),
     else:
           n=n-1
           print n,
           print kaboom(n-2),
   print n,    
   n=n+1
   return n
```

*the output is*

kaboom(5)

```
4 2 0 None 0 1 2 3 4

5
```

kaboom(4)

```
4 2 0 None 0 1 2 3 4
```

5

**but it should be**

kaboom(5)

```
4 2 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

*and*

kaboom(4)

```
4 2 0 1 2 3 4
```

and by the way this is not homework :)

Comment: That’s not the actual output.

Comment: Recursion is a powerful method, but for my life I cannot see why to use a recursive function here when a one-line generator expression would be clearer and faster. Also: a function that prints values is unusable, you should always yield values and let the caller decide what to do with them.

Comment: @tokland, just saw this comment, I provided your solution below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Print the even numbers on the way "down" through the recursion, and print each number on the way "back", reducing by 1 each time. Use `,` after the print statement to follow the number with a space instead of a newline. Don't return a value and don't print a returned value.

```
def kaboom(n):
    if (n % 2) == 0: print n,
    if n == 0: return # we "hit bottom"
    kaboom(n-1) # make the recursive call
    # From this point on, we are "on the way back", and print each value.
    print n,
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def kaboom(n):
    if n >= 0:
        if n%2 == 0:
            print n,
        kaboom (n-1)
    if n > 0:
        print n,
```

Test:

```
>>>  kaboom(4)
4 2 0 1 2 3 4
>>> kaboom(5)
4 2 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the itertools way to do it.
No recursion:

```
from itertools import chain, imap
def even_down_all_up(x):
    return ' '.join(imap(str, chain(xrange(x-1 if x%2 else x, 0, -1), xrange(0, x+1))))

print even_down_all_up(5)
4 2 0 1 2 3 4 5

print even_down_all_up(4)
4 2 0 1 2 3 4
```

Iterator only version returning strings:

```
from itertools import chain, imap
def even_down_all_up(x):
    return imap(str, chain(xrange(x-1 if x%2 else x, 0, -1), xrange(0, x+1)))

print list(even_down_all_up(5))
['4', '2', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

print tuple(even_down_all_up(4))
('4', '2', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4')
```

Iterator version returning ints

```
from itertools import chain, imap
def even_down_all_up(x):
    return chain(xrange(x-1 if x%2 else x, 0, -1), xrange(0, x+1))

print tuple(even_down_all_up(4))
(4, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

NOTE: I love stackoverflow for giving me questions to apply itertools to . :)
EDIT: Added int returning version.

Comment: Hi there, coming from the main comments :-) I guess you agree that there is no point in doing a recursion version of this. I had also written a very similar code, only that I had the first xrange this way: xrange(n & ~1, -1, -2). I'd say that the "int version" is probably enough, no need to map elements to string.

Comment: +1 I really like your bitwise and with the complement of one.  That is simple and clean, thx for sharing.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need 2 recursive functions (in VB.Net because I don't know python) :

```
Function AllNumbers(ByVal n As Integer) As String
    If n > 0 Then
        Return AllNumbers(n - 1) & " " & n
    Else
        Return ""
    End If
End Function

Function EvenNumbers(ByVal n As Integer) As String
    If n > 0 Then
        If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Return n.ToString & " " & EvenNumbers(n - 2)
        Else
            Return EvenNumbers(n - 1)
        End If
    Else
        Return "0"
    End If
End Function

Function Kaboom(ByVal n As Integer) As String
    Return EvenNumbers(n) & AllNumbers(n)
End Function
```